# Uploading split apk in playstore

Tags: android, apk

I have developed an app its apk size is too big (after  enabling progaurd,reducing image size ,running lint)I am thinking of using split apk.I have used abi split which apks should i upload so that I can cover maximum devices ? I want to upload only two is that possible ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

> Multiple APK support is a feature on Google Play that allows you to
>   publish different APKs for your application that are each targeted to
>   different device configurations. Each APK is a complete and
>   independent version of your application, but they share the same
>   application listing on Google Play and must share the same package
>   name and be signed with the same release key. This feature is useful
>   for cases in which your application cannot reach all desired devices
>   with a single APK.

[How Multiple APKs Work](https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html#HowItWorks)

The concept for using multiple APKs on Google Play is that you have just one entry in Google Play for your application, but different devices might download a different APK.

[Creating Multiple APKs](https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html#CreatingApks)

Once you decide to publish multiple APKs, you probably need to create separate Android projects for each APK you intend to publish so that you can appropriately develop them separately.

Aditional  Refrence:

1. http://developer.sonymobile.com/knowledge-base/tutorials/ui-graphics/use-the-multiple-apk-support-in-android-market-2/
2. https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/OldFiles/docs/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html
3. https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-apks/index.html

Comment: Thats very informative mate what i wanted to know is that if i upload only arm and x86 will that cover all the devices in playstore ??

Comment: @DwijrajBhattacharyya you can check this 1) http://stackoverflow.com/a/37248176/3758024  2)http://stackoverflow.com/a/39622499/3758024